# I am receiving an AttributeError when calling init items in a user defined class

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, init, python-class

```
class Schedule():
    def __init__(self,  master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Schedule')
        master.geometry('800x800')
        self.Main = Frame(self.master)
        self.Main.pack(fill = BOTH)

        #Widgets        
        self.treeFrame = Frame(self.Main, height = 690, width = 800)
        self.treeFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM, expand = False)
        self.PGvariable = StringVar()
        self.PGvariable.set(ProduktionsGruppe[0])
        self.ProduktionsGruppeOptionMenu = OptionMenu(self.optionsFrame, self.PGvariable, 
                    'Gruppe auswählen', *ProduktionsGruppe.values(), command = Schedule.selectPG)
        self.ProduktionsGruppeOptionMenu.pack(pady = 10)


        self.tree = Treeview(self.treeFrame, show = 'headings', height = 32)

        self.selectPG()


    def selectPG(self):
        
        #delete existing tree
        for i in self.tree.get_children():
            self.tree.delete(i)
        
        #get production group selection
        PGselection = self.PGvariable.get()
        global PGselectionint
        self.PGvariable.set(ProduktionsGruppe[PGselectionint])
        
        #create tree with list of selected group's names as columns
        treeview_columns = listofnumberlists[PGselectionint]
        self.tree['columns'] = treeview_columns

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    Schedule(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is the relevant portion of the code. It is meant to display a treeview that can be changed by the user selecting an option from the OptionMenu. When I run it, it pulls up the treeview fine, but when I select an option from the Option menu I get this AttributeError

```
for i in self.tree.get_children():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tree'
```

The same error comes up during every instance where I try to call a variable from the **init** function in a different function within the class.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: AFAICT ~ You are calling the method wrong, `Schedule.selectPG(self)` should be `self.selectPG()`

Comment: Thanks - I am still receiving the error, though.

Comment: Remove redundant parentheses from Class

Comment: I tried the code, I dont receive that error.

Comment: You need to change `command = Schedule.selectPG` to `command=self.selectPG` as well.  But then you will get another exception after you have selected a value in the option menu.

Comment: This gave me another error. (TypeError: selectPG() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given)

Comment: It is because callback for the `command` option of `OptionMenu` expects an argument, the *selected value*.